# How to show child elements as parents using angular 6 ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a JSON data set which itself is an array, and each object may contain sub arrays.

I need to show the elements in the inner nested array as elements of parent array, to be displayed using Angular `NgFor.`

The following is my input format:

```
[{
  'id': 1,
  'title': 'One',
  'data': [{
    'id': 200,
    'dataset': [{
        'id': 300,
        'name': 'Duke',
      },
      {
        'id': 301,
        'name': 'Bajaj'
      }
    ]
  }]
}]
```

I need to display as:

```
1  One (outer element)
   300   Duke (innermost element)
   301   Bajaj
```

Comment: what you have tried? where is the problem you faced???

Comment: I tried ngFor inside parent ngFor, but, unable to get an idea on how to get reference to the third level.

Comment: you can use KeyValue pipe for simplify this loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the data. Use `*ngFor`. Fo third level you may need another nested `*ngFor` since `data` is again an array inside another array

In html file

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <li>{{item.title}}</li>
  <li *ngFor="let elem of item.data; let x = index2">

    <div *ngFor="let name of elem.dataset; let y = index3">
      <span>{{name.id}}</span><span>{{name.name}}</span>
    </div>


  </li>
</ul>
```

In component file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  data;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [{
      'id': 1,
      'title': 'One',
      'data': [{
        'id': 200,
        'dataset': [{
            'id': 300,
            'name': 'Duke',
          },
          {
            'id': 301,
            'name': 'Bajaj'
          }
        ]
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcglxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)